# Worksheet.Activate does not trigger the Worksheet_Activate event

Tags: excel, vba

I created macros in vba but they don't work.

In the ThisWorkbook code I wrote:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```

In the code of Sheet1 (Sheet1) I wrote:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    MsgBox ("hello")
End Sub
```

but when I open the file nothing happens ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Sheet1` is already active when you open the workbook, then

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

does exactly nothing. Because you cannot activate what is already active.

Test it by adding 2 Sheets `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. Then select `Sheet2` save the file and close it. Now open it again, it will run `Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate` and this will trigger the `Worksheet_Activate` properly.

Also note that `MsgBox ("hello")` should be without parenthesis as it does not return a value to a variable: `MsgBox "hello"`

---

An alternative solution is:

Write in a module:

```
Public Sub Sheet1_Activate()
     MsgBox "Sheet1 Activate"
End Sub
```

In Sheet1 write:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Sheet1_Activate
End Sub
```

And in ThisWorkbook write:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        Sheet1_Activate
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

The idea is to have a new procedure `Sheet1_Activate` that takes the actual code and is triggered by the `Worksheet_Activate` as well as by the `Workbook_Open` in case the sheet is already the active sheet.

Comment: @DanieleCinquanta see my edit for an alternative solution how to get around that problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub auto_open()
   MsgBox "HueHueHue"
End Sub
```

You can't activate the same thing twice.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to remove the parenthesis.

Comment: I tried to put it in both Worksheet code and Workbook code (without the brackets) but it doesn't work...

Comment: As it's own complete seperate sub?

Comment: @XylozQuin Actually `auto_open` runs on opening of the workbook and not on activating the worksheet so it is the same as `Workbook_Open`. And it does something entirely different from what the OP was doing because then he could have put his code in `Workbook_Open` directly what obviosly was not what he tried to do. • Note that good answers should always contain a descriptive text that explains why/how that solves the OPs issue and how it works (see [answer]). I don't see how this would solve the issue the OP has.

Comment: `but when I open the file nothing happens ...` Please tell me more about how my answer is not on spec.  They specified on file open.

What they are doing is activating a sheet and then doing a message,,, so skip all that and do the message. Not my problem you and OP are assuming lots of things that are not written down.

Comment: What I meant ist that clearly the OP wants the message everytime the sheet1 gets activated (thats why he used `Worksheet_Activate`). The issue is that it doesn't popup when the workbook opens because the sheet is already active. That is why he tried to activate it again in the `Workbook_Open` event but that didn't work for the same reason. See my edited answer for an alternative how to solve that. In that case it will show the box on every activation of the sheet and also if you open the workbook with that sheet already active.